# Remove restrictions from certificate-encrypted pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, read-only

Recently I was given a pdf written by students (free to use) and its relative certificate. Installed the certificate (using the psw given to me by them) I managed to open the pdf with adobe acrobat, but I have everything blocked, I can do absolutely nothing but read it. this is a rip off as I would like to print it and be able to modify it by adding my notes. since they have not answered me anymore I would like to find a way to change it. is it possible to do something? (apart from making screenshots of each page) Thanks in advance to everyone for the answers

**Update**:

- I tried qpdf, convert pdf to .ps and use Ghostscript and gview, they all give me "**unknown encryption" error**. I don't really know what to look for, because everyone can unlock password-locked files, but I found little information on certificates.
- The file opens with acrobat, and foxit, but not with edge and chrome.
  the certificate to be installed is in .pfx
- In the "digital IDs" I have mine, obviously theirs used for "digital signature, ecnrypt documentm key agreement" and that of the client
- I took 600 screenshots of every single page, horizontally and in full screen in 1080, the problem is that the OCR misses 40% of the words.
- **I followed the procedure to protect a pdf file with acrobat, it just becomes read-only and that's it, even the author has no other way to remove the restrictions.**

*I don't know how to make you understand that the pdf has no copyright or anything, it's just notes and that's it. Thanks for the time wasted on my question.*

Steps for creating the certificate:

1. select encryption algorithm
2. Create a digital ID using for example a pckcs # 12 file, associate name etc. and protect it from psw
3. select the id and subsequently you can change the permissions, when
   the permissions change

> adobe warns that adobe products, which impose
> limitations, used by other manufacturers may not respect these
> settings and may be able to ignore some of the limitations.

4. you can limit everything except reading the text for the visually
   impaired
5. adobe warns that the settings will be enabled after
   saving the file

Comment: 'Rip-off' implies it wasn't worth the money you paid for it. As you were given it, with restrictions, you got what you paid for.

Comment: You're still asking us to help you pirate something you have no rights to. If you need an unlocked version you should speak to the supplier.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the required certificate, or the necessary information, to allow editing to the PDF.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if the document does or doesn’t have copyright, the document is encrypted, and you don’t have the required certificate to print the document

Answer (score 1):

As printing and copying content are willfully placed settings in a pdf, it seems like your students understanding of "using" the document implies only reading it.

Your only lawful option at this point is to get in touch with the copyright holder.
Even the creation of screenshots could be illegal depending on where your university is located.